# POST request not including payload data in Electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, electron

I'm trying to get my server to accept bug reports and feature requests sent from within my Electron app. Using either the `net.requests` or `https` module on the main thread, GET requests work perfectly fine, but POST seems to not include the data no matter what I try. I successfully get a 200 response, but also a server-side error saying that the sent key is not found. The server script works when testing using Postman, so I don't think that's where the problem lies.

My code:

```js
const payload = JSON.stringify({report: "1234"});

const request = net.request({
    method: 'POST',
    protocol: 'https:',
    hostname: 'site.tld',
    path: '/backend-script.php',
    redirect: 'follow'
});

request.on('response', (response) => {
    console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`);
    console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(response.headers)}`);

    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`)
    });
});

request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.write(payload, 'utf-8');
request.end();
```

Using the `net.requests` module Both GET and POST requests do give me the following messages in the console:

```
Request is Finished
Last Transaction has occurred
[91902:0301/111653.091508:ERROR:trust_store_mac.cc(838)] Error parsing certificate:
ERROR: Failed parsing extensions
```

but considering `https` doesn't complain at all, I'm also tempted to rule this out as the cause.

I've tried logging all incoming POST data on the server side, and anything sent from Electron includes no data whatsoever, whereas Postman works as expected.

Any ideas would be very welcome.

Comment: Seems as a certificate issue, tried protocol: 'http:' ?

Comment: _"whereas Postman works as expected"_ - then you are probably _not_ sending the same request in there. Where is the server-side part of this, how are you trying to access this data in PHP?

Comment: @ion I did, though I think I have my server configured to always redirect anyway.

@CBroe I'm sure Postman is doing *something* different, I just have no idea what. I am simply reading `$_POST["report"]` in PHP, though right now I'm also echoing all POST values just to debug.

`foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { echo "Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";}`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was sending my request with `Content-Type: application/json`, and then trying to read it from the `$_POST` array in PHP. Using a different content type + format (i.e.: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `report=my_json_string`), or reading the JSON in PHP by using `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))->report;` instead works as expected. TIL.